# How to detect when home button is pressed in react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-sound-player](https://github.com/johnsonsu/react-native-sound-player) to play some sounds, which I want to be stopped when exiting the app.

In android, I've tried to use [react-native-home-pressed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-pressed):

```
componentDidMount() {
  DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("ON_HOME_BUTTON_PRESSED", () => {
    SoundPlayer.stop();
  });
}
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you share us some more logs? What if DeviceEventEmitter was not set up properly. What do you see when you log it like below before using it? ```console.log('DeviceEventEmitter is", typeof DeviceEventEmitter, Object.keys(DeviceEventEmitter)); console.log("DeviceEventEmitter.addListener", typeof DeviceEventEmitter.addListener)```

Comment: If you want to know when the user exits the app you can listen to changes of **AppState**: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Comment: @moritzw that is what I was looking for